# Where am I suppose to add a USER to a GROUP in django?

Tags: django

In models.py i have the following code:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField("Nome",max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=256) # A CharField that checks that the value is a valid email address using EmailValidator.
    phone_number = models.CharField("Número de telemóvel", max_length=9)
    cc = models.CharField("Número de cartão de cidadão", max_length=8, unique=True)
    nif = models.CharField("Número de identificação fiscal", max_length=9, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField("Morada", max_length=200)
    cp = models.CharField("Código de postal", max_length=8)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) #guarda automaticamente a data a que foi criado

    def __str__(self):
        return str((str(self.name), str(self.cc), str(self.nif), str(self.date)))


class AppUser(Profile):
    TYPES = [
        ('A', 'Admin'),
        ('M', 'Medic'),
        ('S', 'Secretary'),
    ]
    type = models.CharField("Tipo",max_length=1, choices=TYPES)
```

I want to check the type of a user and add it to a certain group. Where do i write that code?
I know there is a way to do it in the shell but i was wondering if there is another way.

Every time i create a user I'd like to add to the correct group based on the type.
The following code is more or less what i want to happen:

```
if type == 'A':
        user_id = Profile.user
        mygroup, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Admin')
        a = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        mygroup.user_set.add(a)
        mygroup.save()
```

Also, i don't know if the code above is correctly defined.

Comment: Is this every time you create a `User` or a `Profile`? How are you creating these users/profiles?

Answer (score 0):

I don't if it the corret way, but it works in the views.py if o do it like this:

```
def add_profile(request):
    print(request.method)
    form = ExtendedUserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        print(user)
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user
        print(profile)
        profile.save()

        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)

        type = profile_form.cleaned_data.get('type')

        if type == 'A':
            user = User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'))
            mygroup, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Admin')
            mygroup.user_set.add(user)
            mygroup.save()

        if type == 'M':
            user = User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'))
            mygroup, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Medic')
            mygroup.user_set.add(user)
            mygroup.save()

        if type == 'S':
            user = User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'))
            mygroup, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Secretary')
            mygroup.user_set.add(user)
            mygroup.save()

        return redirect('webapp:home')
```